# get a feedback when video is playing -mediaelementjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

Is there any option that the player (mediaelementjs) give a feedback (call a function) when it starts playing and after the video is stopped?

In the documentation I didn't find such an option.

Best
max

Answer (score 0):

This may be a partial solution. I'm not sure if it will work, but it's worth a try:

```
new MediaElement('player1', {
    flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
    defaultVideoWidth: 480,
    defaultVideoHeight: 270,
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
        mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {             
            document.getElementById('current-time').innerHTML = mediaElement.currentTime;
        }, false);

        // insert code to run before playing
        mediaElement.play();
        // insert code to run after playing 
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks.
I tried it but doesn't work with running code when the button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Use play or ended events

```
  new MediaElementPlayer('#player',{
    success: function(media){
      media.addEventListener("play",function(){
        //code when the video is played     
      });
      media.addEventListener("ended",function(){
        //code when the video has ended     
      });
    }
  });
```